# How to invert INDEX formula in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet named NYSEDB with stock names in column A and the companies that issued them in column B.

In another sheet I have companies in cells B2 and C2 (for example, AAPL, GOOGL etc.).

I have the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX(NYSEDB!$A:$B,SMALL(IF(NYSEDB!$B:$B={$B$2,$C$2},ROW(NYSEDB!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),1,1),""))
```

This formula, when I spread it down the sheet, returns all the stocks from NYSEDB that are issued by the companies I have specified in B2 and C2.

How can I make the exact opposite formula and "invert" the task - I want for the formula to show all stocks from NYSEDB WITHOUT those issued by the companies I have specified in B2 and C2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Use the not equal operand `<>` instead of the equal one `=`.

In this case It's better to use the `QUERY` function. Which is effectively more expressive than an `IF` statement and makes exclusion straightforward using an array of exceptions.

Your formula will be then like:

```
=QUERY(NYSEDB!A:B, "select A where B<>'"&TEXTJOIN("' and B<>'", TRUE, B2:C2)&"'", -1)
```

Note: you can add as many exceptions as you want, but you will have to edit the `B2:C2` range in the `QUERY` formula.

In this way the `Query` function will return the column `A` value whenever the column B value is not included in the exception row.

### Reference

[QUERY Formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work with two companies. If I add the <> and compare it with one cell, for example B2, it works, but if I compare it with both B2 and C2 it starts to not work. I basically mean =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX(NYSEDB!$A:$B,SMALL(IF(NYSEDB!$B:$B<>$B$2,ROW(NYSEDB!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),1,1),"")) works and =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX(NYSEDB!$A:$B,SMALL(IF(NYSEDB!$B:$B<>{$B$2,$C$2},ROW(NYSEDB!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),1,1),"")) doesn't.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/raoQGEW  Please check the screenshots attached; I could add you to the Google sheet as well, if it will be easier for you

Comment: Please share it publicly here. Or show the input. Because from your screenshot i cannot see the source of the arrayformula statement. It can be an example as well (not real data, if you don't want to share it)

Comment: Sorry my mistake I went to the wrong direction giving you the hint. In this case i think it's better to use query. I edited my answer.

Comment: Alessandro, please check your email at hotmail.it!